# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting the below exception when I invoke java.time.LocalDateTime.now() all of a sudden continuously.
The same code was working fine before.

Can somebody please let me know what could be the reason? Thanks in advance.

```
Exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider
at java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)
at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)
at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:359)
at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:315)
at java.util.TimeZone.toZoneId(TimeZone.java:556)
at java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault(ZoneId.java:274)
at java.time.Clock.systemDefaultZone(Clock.java:178)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.now(LocalDateTime.java:180)
at com.bosch.itrams.ccm.dependentmods.TelephonyFixDetection.handleEvent(TelephonyFixDetection.java:112)
at com.prosyst.mbs.impl.services.event.HandlerWrapper.deliverEvent(HandlerWrapper.java:430)
at com.prosyst.mbs.impl.services.event.EventAdminImpl.deliverEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:482)
at com.prosyst.mbs.impl.services.event.ASynchQueue.run(ASynchQueue.java:124)
at com.prosyst.mbs.impl.services.core.threads.tpt.threadpool.ExecutorImpl.run(ExecutorImpl.java:221)
```

Comment: I suggest you to read this answer give by Dan W. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493099/mule-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-java-time-zone-zonerules

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` basically means that the _build path_ included the class but it does not exist in the runtime CLASSPATH. Look for differences between the two.

Comment: VinAlph, did this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493099/mule-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-java-time-zone-zonerules) resolve your issue ?